# $ f(z) = \int _{0} ^\infty e^{-z t^2} dt $ is holomorphic in $Re(z) > 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, holomorphic-functions

I've been trying to find a reasonable way to approach this but nothing leads to a reasonable result.

With $z = a + ib$  the last thing I tried looking at was

$$| \frac{f(z) - f(z-h)}{h}| = |\frac{1}{h} \int_{0} ^{\infty} e^{-zt^2} (1 - e^{-ht^2}) dt | \leq \frac{1}{|h|} \int_{0} ^{\infty} |e^{-zt^2}| |1 - e^{-ht^2}| dt$$ 
I do cheat next since I asked wolfram alpha for $ \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{|1 - e^{-ht^2}|}{|h|}  = |t|$ and I'm not 100% on how to prove that.

$$ \leq  \int_{0} ^{\infty} |e^{-at^2}| \frac{|1 - e^{-ht^2}|}{|h|} dt \rightarrow \int_{0} ^{\infty} |t^2e^{-at^2}|dt = \int_{0} ^{\infty} t^2 e^{-at^2} dt $$

I'm not sure how to then get something useful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure that limit should be $|t|^2$.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, thanks. Corrected it.

Comment: Can you show that $f$ is continuous? Then apply Morera's theorem.

Comment: Regarding your question about the limit, note that without the absolute values it is $-\left.\frac{d}{dx} e^{-xt^2}\right|_{x=0}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I run into some problems trying to prove continuity and can't quite prove it really. The morera tip is great though, thanks!

Comment: You can use the dominated convergence theorem to show continuity on $\{ z : \operatorname{Re} z \geqslant \delta\}$ for every $\delta > 0$.

Comment: If you show the integral of the norm of your exponential is uniformly bounded on compact subsets of $\Re z\ge\delta$, then Fubini's theorem and Morera's theorem suffice (without using Lebesgue).